# Dilution Formula

Tags: recreational-mathematics, measurement-theory

I'm completely stumped. I'm trying to figure out a formula for the following...

How much of a solution that is 400 PPM per gallon needs to be added to X amount of gallons of a 0 PPM solution in order for X amount of gallons to be 2 PPM per gallon?

OR

If container A has X amount of gallons of a 0 PPM solution.
And container B has a solution that is 400 PPM per gallon.
How much of the solution from container B has to be added to container A to make X amount of gallons a 2 PPM per gallon solution?

I only know how to work this backward and find out how many 0 PPM gallons it would take to dilute one gallon of a 400 PPM solution to a 2 PPM per gallon solution. Which would be if I add 199 gallons that are 0 PPM to one gallon that is 400 PPM then I would have a total of 200 gallons that were 2 PPM per gallon. I'm lost though on finding a formula to basically do this the opposite way as I described at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Solution A: $400$ ppm/gallon

Solution B: $2$ ppm/gallon

How much solvent ($0$ ppm/gallon) is required? Say $X$

$\frac{1 \text{gallon} \times 400 \text{ppm/gallon}}{(1 + X) \text{gallons}} = 2 \text{ppm/gallon}$

Solve for $X$.

[Answer: $199 \text{gallons}$]

$\frac{V_o\times C_o}{V_o + V_d} = C_e$ (formula)

$V_o$ = volume of original solution taken
$C_o$ = concentration of original solution
$V_o \times C_o$ = amount of solute in $V_o$ units of the original solution
$V_d$ = volume of diluent (pure solvent)
$V_o + V_d$ = total volume when you mix $V_o$ of original solution (which contains $V_o \times C_o$ of solute) with $V_d$ of solvent/diluent.
The end concentration (post-mixing) = $C_e = \frac{V_o \times C_o}{V_o + V_d}$

Comment: I think I explained it wrong.

Solution A: 400 ppm/gallon

Solution B: 50 gallons of 0 ppm/gallon (Using 50 for explanation purposes but the purpose of the formula would be to plug whatever amount into that.)

How much of Solution A needs to be added to Solution B to raise the 50 gallons that are currently 0 ppm/gallon to 2 ppm/gallon.? Say X

Comment: I think I actually figured out the correct formula and if this is it then I need to go back to school because it's simply a matter of solving for X in the most basic way.. Hopefully you could confirm that I'm correct.

(400ppm)X = (2ppm)(50gallons) = 1/4 gallons of the 400ppm solution need to be added to the 50 gallons to get a 2ppm/gallon solution. I think it would actually be added to 49.75 gallons so with the 1/4 gallons of 400ppm/gallon solution it totals 50 gallons.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Hope it solves the problem you're facing. Here's a helpful link: [dilution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilution_(equation))

Comment: If you want to grok it intuitively, answer this question: I have a 2 mg/mL sugar solution. What should I do to end up with a 1 mg/mL sugar solution. I don't think removing sugar is among your options. . I have to add water (the point of *dilution*). How much? Do I *double* the volume of my solution? Yes, but I only want a few mL of 1 mg/mL sugar solution and I need the original solution for other purposes. I could take 1 mL of the 2 mg/mL solution. Then add 1 mL of water: $\frac{2 mg}{2mL} = 1mg/mL$